# fit() vs fit_predict() metthods in sklearn KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

There are two methods when we make a model on `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`. First is `fit()` and other is `fit_predict()`. My understanding is that when we use `fit()` method on `KMeans` model, it gives an attribute `labels_` which basically holds the info on which observation belong to which cluster. `fit_predict()` also have `labels_` attribute.

So my question are,

1. If `fit()` fulfills the need then why their is `fit_predict()`?
2. Are `fit()` and `fit_predict()` interchangeable while writing code?

Answer (score 8):

`KMeans` is just one of the many models that `sklearn` has, and many share the same API. The basic functions ae `fit`, which teaches the model using examples, and `predict`, which uses the knowledge obtained by `fit` to answer questions on potentially new values.

`KMeans` will automatically predict the cluster of all the input data during the training, because doing so is integral to the algorithm. It keeps them around for efficiency, because predicting the labels for the original dataset is very common. Thus, `fit_predict` adds very little: it calls `fit`, then returns `.labels_`. `fit_predict` is just a convenience method that calls `fit`, then returns the labels of the training dataset. (`fit_predict` doesn't have a `labels_` attribute, it just gives you the labels.)

However, if you want to train your model on one set of data and then use this to quickly (and without changing the established cluster boundaries) get an answer for a data point that was not in the original data, you would need to use `predict`, not `fit_predict`.

In other models (for example `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`), training can be a very expensive operation so you may not want to re-train a model every time you want to predict something; also, it may not be a given that the prediction result is generated as a part of the prediction. Or, as discussed above, you just don't want to change the model in response to new data. In those cases, you cannot get predictions from the result of `fit`: you need to call `predict` with the data you want to get a prediction on.

Also note that `labels_` is marked with an underscore, a Python convention for "don't touch this, it's private" (in absence of actual access control). Whenever possible, you should use the established API instead.

Answer (score 1):

In scikit-learn, there are similar things such as `fit` and `fit_transform`. 
`Fit` and `predict` or `labels_` are essential for clustering. 
Thus `fit_predict` is just efficient code, and its result is the same as the result from fit and predict (or labels).

In addition, the fitted clustering model is used only once when determining cluster labels of samples.